# Basic question regarding plugin

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi guys. I have basic questions regarding plugins and I am using Gazebo with ROS. Firstly, in the plugin examples given in the tutorial, there is no main function, only class declaration. So how are the functions within the class in the plugin implemented? Is it that all the functions in “public” will be executed?

Secondly, can I know what this piece of code does?

```
// Listen to the update event. This event is broadcast every
      // simulation iteration.
      this->updateConnection = event::Events::ConnectWorldUpdateStart(
          boost::bind(&ModelPush::OnUpdate, this));
```

From what I gather, this means that the ModelPush is binded as a function pointer and it will be call every time the world update by receiving a "world update" signal. Am I right?

If so, why is it that in the "Hello world" example ([the first tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.0/plugins/overview)), the print function will executed?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/944/basic-question-regarding-plugin/) by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 17 on 2013-01-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Plugins do not have a main() function, they are objects that are created by the main gazebo process. The print function in the example gets called, because the constructor HelloWorld::HelloWorld() is called when the object is created (really elementary C++ knowledge).

> From what I gather, this means that the ModelPush is binded as a function pointer and it will be call every time the world update by receiving a "world update" signal. Am I right?

Almost. The method ModelPush::OnUpdate() of your ModelPush object (this)is called on world update.

---

Originally posted by [r0nald](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/138/r0nald/) with karma: 62 on 2013-01-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ChengXiang](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/54/chengxiang/) on 2013-01-21**:
I see. Thanks for clarifying!